# How to migrate the SQL data between two subscriptions in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azureportal

I have created a new subscription in azure and want to transfer all the SQL data from the Old subscription to the new One. Is there any ways I can do it through azure portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can move all of you Azure SQL resource to another subscription on Portal.

Go to your Resource Group, Move--> Move to another subscription:

[image]

Select the Azure SQL resource and the subscription you want to move to:

[image]

**Update:**

Congratulations that saon have solved this with Azure SQL Sync features.

Hope this helps.

Comment: already tried this approach and found that it just moved the resources but not the data, also it's something that is not recommended

Comment: @saon I have edited my answer,you  can select all the Azure SQL resources( include the databases and Server) and the subscription (resource group in the subscription) which you want to move to. Please see my screenshot.

Comment: I used move my Azure SQL Server and databases to another resource group, it doesn't matter about the data in the database.

Comment: Already did it by using the Sync Database features but Thanks for all the instructions.Next time will try this approach as well...

Comment: @saon Congratulations! Can I add this to my answer? Then others can know your error is solved by yourself now. You can accept is as the answer, This can be beneficial to other community members.Thank you very much!

Comment: sure, you can do

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure "Data Factory" service : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps

**Step 1 : Create a new Azure SQL Server on a different resource group.**

```
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer -Location "West US" -AdministratorLogin "AdminLogin"  -AdministratorLoginPassword "AdminPassword"
```

**Step 2 : Copy the source database to the newly created Azure SQL Server.**

```
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName "SourceServer" -DatabaseName "Orders" -PartnerServer "NewlyCreatedServer" -PartnerDatabase "OrdersCopy"
```

**Step 3 :  Move the resource group of the Newly created Azure SQL Server to another subscription.**

```
Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName [-DestinationSubscriptionId ] -ResourceId
```

Comment: I have already created the resources using ARM(Azure Resource Manager) Template.So, not sure those steps will help me to export the data itself